# custom fields liferay language support

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I have custom field with input text. I have added arabic language support in control panel

but when I insert an arabic word it says ***Users and Organizations is temporarily unavailable.***

How to solve this issue?

This is what happened in console log:

```
10:29:49,421 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-17][JDBCExceptionReporter:82] Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xB9\xD8\xB1\xD8\xA8...' for column 'data_' at row 1
10:29:51,254 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-17][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xB9\xD8\xB1\xD8\xA8...' for column 'data_' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2006)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1467)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1135)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2412)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2875)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
```

Comment: We need the error traced in portal log to understand the problem

Comment: i have edited the question with console log

Comment: have you changed the character encoding of the table as well?

Comment: yes thank you 

can you help me with this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145116/users-and-organization-creation-form

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.codeka.com.au/blog/2014/02/unicode-support-in-mysql-is--

and https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7317519.

Basically it is because of the incorrect character encoding set for your database.

Comment: i have changed the database encoding to utf8_general_ci and still the same problem

Comment: Change it to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and try. I think you should read the post fully.